# Validate form input before sending to external url ( Paypal )

Tags: php, paypal

I am currently working on a system that gives users a "bank" balance, users deposit funds through paypal and it updates in the database to reflect what they deposited etc. I have set this up before with paypal buttons but i am now working with a input text box and i want to secure the entire process. This is what i currently have for the form

```
<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' target='_top' name='_xclick'>
                <!-- Identify Business -->
                <input type='hidden' name='business' value='email goes here'>

                <!-- Identify Button Type - Buy it Now Button -->
                <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>

                <!-- Identify Item Details -->
                <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
                <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Bank Deposit'>
                <input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='' id='item_number'>

                How Much Do You Want to Add
                $ <input type='text' name='bank_deposit' placeholder='Amount to deposit' id='bank_deposit' onchange='BankDeposit(this.value)'>

                <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='' id='amount'>

                <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='$user_id'>
                <input name='notify_url' value='ipn url here' type='hidden'>
                <input type='hidden' name='lc' value='US'>
                <input type='hidden' name='bn' value='PP-BuyNowBF'>
                <button type='submit' class='btn_blue' style='border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;'>Add To Bank</button>
            </form>
```

I would preferably like to validate all input through php on my end and then send all post data over to paypal securely once things have been validated. If anyone could provide insight on how to do this it would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke PayPal api using curl and follow the express checkout workflow. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/

you Will see that Will be PayPal to validate the input during the handshake. The validation is inside the token. If a user try to alter any amount the token Will fail

Comment: Do you mean using header() to redirect to the paypal url once the form is validated?

Comment: Yes, it can be a solution

Comment: Aldo you can call PayPal api using curl, but this is another approch. (better in My opinion)

Comment: I attempted the header redirect did not work. I am gathering opinions i already have the ipn set up to validate and perform database update the only thing i am missing is the validation. At the moment a user can alter the hidden input fields and add $100 by paying $1.

Answer (score 0):

First, a more secure approach would be to collect user input and then perform validation and POST your validated message to your payment handler (paypal) code-side.

However, if your IPN is set up and referenced properly then you shouldn't need to worry much because database changes should only take place when your listener receives the appropriate, validated IPN message. The payment amounts in the message will be the actual transactions as reported by paypal and can be trusted.